# css space between elements inside relative div

Tags: html, css

i havent found answer to my question.

I have these two divs. I want that the link appear at the bottom of top div.
Its works but i can not add space between elements

```
    #top{background:white;
height:200px;
text-decoration:none;
position:relative;
}

#menu a{text-decoration:none;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
margin-left:10px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7x4zvf4/

The result is without any space between elements.
I can understand that using relative positions influence the rest positioning,for example padding and margins but have't figured out why.

Comment: They're all in the same spot. Either don't use absolute positioning or change their (top/right/bottom/left)  position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using

```
#menu a {
    position:absolute;
}
```

you remove each `<a>` from the normal flow **individually** so `margin-left` has no effect because there is nothing to the left of each element (or in any other direction) that can influence the position of these elements.

Remove the `position:absolute` from your `#menu a` and add it to your `#menu`, that way you position the element containing all of your anchors at the bottom of your `div#top` while the inside elements are positioned "normally" i.e. relative to each other.

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7x4zvf4/10/)

Comment: thank you for your solution its works as i expect.
Is the bottom:0; necceserly by #menu a?
If i delete is still works

Comment: No, `bottom:0;` is not necessary for `#menu a`, I left it in there by accident, updated my answer to remove it.

Comment: sorry i can not add you more score thank you soo much the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

No need to use positioning for this - just give your #top a `margin-top`, like so;

```
#top {
    margin-top: 200px;
}


#menu a {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7txj730h/)

Comment: I always feel that repeating values (like `200px` in this example) is a bad idea because if you ever decide to change the height of the container you'll have a lot more work adjusting all values. It might be just my personal feeling, but it reminds me of hardcoding stuff that shouldn't be hardcoded

Comment: sorry but i need to practise the using of relative and absolute stufss,even it is works i can not use now.but thank you for you effort